# Calculate levenshteinDist between rownames and colnames using mapply

Tags: r, matrix, levenshtein-distance, mapply

I want to calculate levenshteinDist distance between the rownames and colnames of a matrix using mapply function: Because the volume of may matrix is too big and using a nested loop "for" take a very long time to give me the result.

Here's the old code with nested loop:

```
mymatrix  <- matrix(NA, nrow=ncol(dataframe),ncol=ncol(dataframe),dimnames=list(colnames(dataframe),colnames(dataframe)))
distfunction = function (text1, text2) {return(1 - (levenshteinDist(text1, text2)/max(nchar(text1), nchar(text2))))}
for(i in 1:ncol(mymatrix))
{
  for(j in 1:nrow(mymatrix))

   mymatrix[i,j]=(distfunction(rownames(mymatrix)[i], colnames(mymatrix)[j]))*100
 }
```

I tried to switch nested loop by mapply:

```
   mapply(distfunction,mymatrix)
```

It gave me this error:

```
   Error in typeof(str2) : argument "text2" is missing, with no default
```

I planned to apply the levenshteinDist distance to my matrix and then conclude how to apply myfunction.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `mapply` cannot be used in this context. It requires two input vectors and the function is applied to the first elements, second elements, .. and so on. But you want all combinations applied.

You could try a stacked `sapply`

```
sapply(colnames(mymatrix), function(col) 
  sapply(rownames(mymatrix), function(row) 
    distfunction(row, col)))*100
```

#### Simple usage example

```
sapply(1:3, function(x) sapply(1:4, function(y) x*y))
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
[4,]    4    8   12
```

#### Update

Even better is to use `outer` but i think your `distfunction` is not vectorized (due to the `max`). So use the wrapper function `Vectorize`:

```
distfunction_vec <- Vectorize(distfunction)
outer(rownames(mymatrix), rownames(mymatrix), distfunction_vec)
```

But I'm not sure about the performance penalty. Better to directly vectorize the function (probably with `pmax`).

Comment: Thank you @DeltaKappa. I'll try this solution. Hope that reduces the execution time.

Comment: Your solution worked on my script like a charm ! Thank you so much @DeltaKappa. You're genius.

Comment: I was trying your solution "update", hoping that i'll get a reduced time execution. But it seems that my function can't be vectorized : I switched `max` by `pmax` and I ran `distfunction_vec<-Vectorize(distfunction)` but `is.vector(distfunction_vec)` gave me `FALSE`. Any idea?

Comment: `Vectorize` creates just a thin wrapper around the function so `is.vector()` will not return `TRUE` for a vectorized function. Its just nicer to read with outer. I didn't expect a performance gain.